# AngularJS more than one select in one div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to more than one select in one div. But first select getting own list and can show up but second and other cannot. I couldn't manage that.

I added script link.

```html
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-app="myFruitsApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x.model for x in cars">
</select>
<select ng-model="selectedFruit" ng-options="y.type for y in fruits">
</select>

<h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.model}}</h1>
<h1>fruits:: {{selectedFruit.type}}</h1>


</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.cars = [
            {model : "Ford Mustang"},
            {model : "Fiat 500"},
            {model : "Volvo XC90"}
        ];
    });
</script>

<script>
    var app2 = angular.module('myFruitsApp',[]);
    app2.controller('myCtrla', function($scope){
        $scope.fruits = [
        {type: "apple"},
        {type: "oranges"},
        {type: "pear"}
        ];
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: _**only one** AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first `ngApp` found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must [manually bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) them using angular.bootstrap instead._ ([Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just one app and controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = [
        {model : "Ford Mustang"},
        {model : "Fiat 500"},
        {model : "Volvo XC90"}
    ];
    $scope.fruits = [
        {type: "apple"},
        {type: "oranges"},
        {type: "pear"}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">        
    <p>Select a car:</p>
    
    <select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x.model for x in cars">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="selectedFruit" ng-options="y.type for y in fruits">
    </select>
    
    <h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.model}}</h1>
    <h1>fruits:: {{selectedFruit.type}}</h1>    
</body>
```